# Groovy maps with Integer keys - 'getAt' in DefaultGroovyMethods cannot be applied to (java.lang.Integer)

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I've just started to practice Groovy and I have a question related to maps and IDEA IDE.

Why IDEA shows me the notification below when I try to use `Integer` as a key for a map? This simple Groovy script works fine and print correct result.

[image: screenshot]

```
list = [4, 7, 3, 7, 7, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 7, 5]

map = [:]
list.each {
    t = map[(it)]
    map[(it)] = t != null ? t + 1 : 1
}

map.each {key, value -> if (value == 1) println key}
```

Comment: and without round brackets? `map[ it ]`

Comment: @daggett YES. have just checked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is caused because IntelliJ IDEA sees `map` variable as `Object` - it seems like IDEA does not follow type inference if static type or keyword `def` is missing in front of the variable. If you take a look at `DefaultGroovyMethods` you will see that there is only one method `getAt` implemented for `Object` type:

```
public static Object getAt(Object self, String property) {
    return InvokerHelper.getProperty(self, property);
}
```

This is why IDEA warns you about missing method `getAt(Object self, Integer property)` because it is not aware that `map` is actually a `Map` and not an `Object`.

Please follow the official Groovy's guideline that says:

> Variables can be defined using either their type (like `String`) or by using the keyword `def`:
>
> ```
> String x
> def o
> ```
>
> ---
>
> *Source: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-semantics.html#_variable_definition*

If you define your variable as

```
def map = [:]
```

IntelliJ wont complain anymore.